# Error Confirm Form Resubmission in Salesforce

Tags: form

I'm trying to create a search page as per [this example](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/01/13/apex-search-with-checkbox-results).

When I run it I get a problem. When the form submits data, I press Back and then Forward in the Browser, my page throws an error : **"Confirm Form Resubmission"** . However, when I check [this demo](http://jeffdouglas-developer-edition.na5.force.com/examples/category_search) I don't get that error.

My code isn't different that the one used in the demo. I think the problem is with my config or the environment. Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: Do you have a rerender in you command button?

Comment: I use cache=true all page, this problem is resolved. Thanks all

Comment: That in and of itself can create other problems unless you account for the fact that the cache=true. You should not set parameters just to get a problem to go away if they have nothing to do with the problem as you can create other problems without knowing it.